# How to locate the username and password element through Selenium WebDriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am attempting to automatically enter my username and password for a particular website with Selenium. I am having trouble finding the element to send the keys to. I have attached the website's HTML code below.

Here is what I am currently using:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_id('UserName').getAttribute('value')
```

Additionally, the website ends in a .bsd which I am not entirely familiar with and think that it could be contributing to the problem.

Thanks.

```html
<html>
        <head> 
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/general.css" type="text/css">                 
          <title>RC Inspection - Risk Control</title>
          <script language="javascript1.3" src="scripts/clientside/badgerAPI.js"></script>
          <script language="javascript1.3" src="scripts/clientside/inspectionClient.js"></script>
          <script language="javascript1.3" src="scripts/clientside/validate.js"></script>
          <script language="javascript1.3" src="scripts/widJETs/JETClient.js"></script>
          <script language="javascript1.3" src="scripts/widJETs/JETDataTable.js"></script>
          <script>var searchParameters;</script>
        </head>     
        <frameset rows="0,95,*" framespacing="0">
 
          <frame name="SystemWin" src="about:blank" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" scrolling="auto">
          <frame name="HeaderWin" src="about:blank" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" scrolling="no">
          <frame name="MainWin" src="Logon.bsd?Lang=English'" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" scrolling="auto"
<html><head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script language="javascript1.3" src="scripts/clientside/XHConn.js"></script>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/logon.css" type="text/css">  
        
        <script language="javascript1.3">
 
          function executeAction(sFunction){

            if (sFunction=='OnLoad') {  
                this.document.MainForm.UserName.focus();
                hide('r5');
            }
            else if (sFunction=='Login') { 
            
               fParms='UserName,T,50,1|Password,T,20,1';

               if(top.validatePage('top.MainWin.document.MainForm',fParms,'English'))
                 top.goPage('LogonUser@Logon.bsd?form=top.MainWin.document.MainForm|target=SystemWin|Lang=English') ;
             }
            else if (sFunction=='ForgotPassword') { 
               hide('r1');
               hide('r2');
               show('r5');
            }
            else if (sFunction=='ResetPassword') { 
        if(top.MainWin.document.MainForm.RP_UserName.value == "") {
          alert('Please enter Your Username');
          return false;
        }       
        var r = confirm("Are you sure you wish to reset your password?");
        if (r == true) {
          try {
              var myConn = new XHConn();
              if (!myConn) alert("XMLHTTP not available. Try a newer/better browser.");
              myConn.connect("ResetPassword@Utilities.bsd", "POST", "RP_UserName="+this.document.MainForm.RP_UserName.value+"&Lang=English", fn_ChangeItem);
          }
          catch(e) {
            var msg = (typeof e == "string") ? e : ((e.message) ? e.message : "Unknown Error");
            alert("Unable to get XML data:\n" + msg);
            return;
          }
        }
            } 
        }
  
              fn_ChangeItem = function (XML) {     
                   eval(XML.responseText) ;
              }
             hide=function (szDivID) {
               if(document.layers)    //NN4+
                 eval("document."+szDivID+".visibility = 'hide'");
               else if(document.getElementById)    //gecko(NN6) + IE 5+
                   {  
            var obj = document.getElementById(szDivID);
                      obj.style.display =  "none";
                   }
               else if(document.all) // IE 4
                     document.all[szDivID].style.display =  "none";
               } 
             show=function (szDivID) {
               if(document.layers)    //NN4+
                    eval("document."+szDivID+".visibility = 'show'");
               else if(document.getElementById)    //gecko(NN6) + IE 5+
                {   var obj = document.getElementById(szDivID);
                    obj.style.display =  "";
                }
               else if(document.all) // IE 4
                   document.all[szDivID].style.display =  "";
               } 
        </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="javascript:executeAction('OnLoad');" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

        <div class="loginwrapper">
            
            <div class="logoncontent">
                <div id="logon_header">
          <img width="341" border="0" src="./images/companylogo.gif">
          
          <div class="logintop">
            Risk Control System <br>
            version 4.5.4.1.5
          </div> 
                </div>
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
                <div id="logon_content">
          <form name="MainForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          
            <div id="r1">
              <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
                <label for="UserName">User Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName" maxlength="50" tabindex="1">
              </div>
              <div style="float:left;">
                <label for="Password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" maxlength="20" tabindex="2" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode=='13') executeAction('Login');">
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
            
            <div id="r2">
              <a class="small" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="executeAction('ForgotPassword');return false;">Forgot Password?</a>
              <span class="action_button green_button"><a href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="3" onclick="executeAction('Login');">Login</a></span>
            </div>
            
            <div id="r5" style="display: none;">
              <label class="rp_label" for="RP_UserName">Please Enter Your Username</label>
              <input type="text" name="RP_UserName" value="" size="30" maxlength="50">&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <!-- <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="executeAction('ResetPassword');return false;">Reset Password</a> -->
              <input type="submit" value="Reset Password" onclick="executeAction('ResetPassword');return false;">
            </div>
          </form> 
        </div>
            </div>
              
      <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
      
      <div class="loginbottom">
        <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.riskcontroltech.com/" target="_blank">Risk Control Technologies Inc.</a> Copyright © 2015. All rights reserved.<br>
        All Trademarks are owned by their respective companies.            
      </div>                      
    </div><!-- end loginwrapper -->
        
      
      
    </body></html>
        </frameset>
   
     
     </html>
```

Comment: Find it using the id. If you want suggestions on how to help you, add the code where you attempt to solve it

Comment: +1 attaching screenshot bad practice, community members will not type html code for you to reproduce your problem, you can add html snip instead of image

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `WebDriverWait`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\To\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

username = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='UserName']")))

# username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='UserName']")
username.send_keys("the useName")

# password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='Password']")

password =wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='Password']")))
password.send_keys("yourPassword")
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: This is what i originally tried running but I received the following error message:             NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"UserName"}
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)

Comment: @Its_code_outside I have updated to xpath... try it now

Comment: It said that the name "wait" is not defined. Also, thank you very much for all the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: no worries. It gave me the TimeoutException though.

Answer (score 0):

To send character sequence to the *username* and *password* field in the particular website as the elements are within a `<frame>` you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following solutions:

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame[name='MainWin'][src^='Logon.bsd?Lang=English']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='UserName']"))).send_keys("Its_code_outside")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label[for='Password']").send_keys("Its_code_outside")
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[@name='MainWin' and starts-with(@src, 'Logon.bsd?Lang=English')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='UserName']"))).send_keys("Its_code_outside")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='Password']").send_keys("Its_code_outside")
    ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I used this and was given the following error message:   WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element.

Comment: @Its_code_outside For which element _Username_ or _Password_?

Comment: it did not specify. (which is the first time this has happened) Normally it has specified either username or password as the error source.

Comment: Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: if it is a local url would it make a difference?